# Delegation of a functionality from method to other in java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, coding-style, delegates

I have written a code, which is being not passed by my code reviewer. I would like to take second opinions from you guys.
I cannot write the exact code, just giving a mock code to give understanding of my question.
Code

```
class A{

  void method1(){
//method1 specific tasks
  callcommon();
}

void method2(){
//method2 specific tasks
 callcommon();
}

void method3(){
//method2 specific tasks
 callcommon();
}

void method4(){
//method2 specific tasks
 callcommon();
}

B callcommon(){
returns new B();
}
```

**According to code reviewer** : I shouldn't delegate creation of object 'B' to callcommon() method, as this is a single line method, it is unnecessary delegation.

**My argument is** : I am separating the creation logic of object 'B' to a separate method, as in future even if the constructor of this method changes, I just need to make change only in one callcommon() method instead of all the 4 methods.

So I want to take your reviews on this.

Comment: You cant call it as a delegation, though, your approach should improves readability.

Answer (score 0):

I think I agree with code reviewer.
You are trying to perform some premature optimisation. The constructor could stay the same, but you have already written three redundant lines of code. If you will do it again in another class - number of redundant lines will double. 
Also, all your 4 methods became less readable.

Comment: Assuming that the constructor gets changed to input some parameters, isnt in that case I need to change at 4 places instead of one

Comment: @VKSingla But the constructor hasn't changed and you don't know that it will.

Comment: @VKSingla nowaday IDEs allow to refactor any entity with all occurencies. Still, if you constructor changes significantly, you will have to refactor calls of callcommon() as well.